# NGRX angular payload or no payload

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

In the NGRX library (https://ngrx.io/), when creating an action that includes data, the examples show a `payload` argument provided to contain this data. Is there a reason I cannot just provide the payload as parameters? The documentation and all examples I can find use a `payload` but there is no real explanation for why. For example:

```
export class CreateEmployeeScheduleError implements Action {
readonly type = CREATE_EMPLOYEE_SCHEDULE_ERROR;
constructor(public payload: {
        error: string,
        requests: ScheduleCreateRequest[],
        requestsRemaining: number
}) {}
}
```

could be written as:

```
export class CreateEmployeeScheduleError implements Action {
readonly type = CREATE_EMPLOYEE_SCHEDULE_ERROR;
constructor(public error: string,
        public requests: ScheduleCreateRequest[],
        public requestsRemaining: number) {}
}
```

This eliminates the need to get the action.payload, as well as the need for a helper function (`map(toPayload)`) and is similar to how I've seen other redux implementation frameworks (NGXS). Is there any reason why I should not do it as the latter?

This would change effects and reducers to be simpler as well.

Comment: Hello ! Very good question. I use the payload parameter myself, but a colleague of mine doesn't, and it works for him ... I don't see complexity when adding payload though.

Comment: payload is just an word ... you can use any other word

Comment: @duardbr seems a bit pointless to package everything up into a payload object when it's already packaged into the action

Comment: the PAYLOAD word is just a name to use as PARAMETER ... it is easy to understand ... to pass it  from action, to effects and reducers using de same word myPARAM, PARAMETERS, PARAMS_ACCOUNT or just payload.

Comment: @duardbr The question is not in the verbiage "payload". The question is why would we define the constructor like this "constructor (public payload: { username: string; password: string })" instead of this "constructor(public username: string, public password: string)". Specifically, turning the two fields into an anonymous object instead of defining two different parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `payload` it's just a convention.
See [Let’s have a chat about Actions and Action Creators within NgRx](https://blog.angularindepth.com/lets-have-a-chat-about-actions-and-action-creators-within-ngrx-41277ecc739d)

From [ngrx.io](https://ngrx.io)

> The interface has a single property, the `type`, represented as a string. The `type` property is for describing the action that will be dispatched in your application. The value of the type comes in the form of `[Source] Event` and is used to provide a context of what category of action it is, and where an action was dispatched from. You add properties to an action to provide additional context or metadata for an action. The most common property is the `payload`, which adds any associated data needed for the action.